# Defining a (scalar) function

Tags: sql-server, function, case

I cannot define a function like this, with case select:

```
SELECT @NoShowRate=(Select case when tblPersonal.AnmeldungenXX = 0 and 
tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO = 0 then 0 
                             when tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - 
    tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO > 0 and tblPersonal.Teilnahmen=0 then 0
                             when tblPersonal.Teilnahmen > 
                                  tblPersonal.Anmeldungen then 100
                              else 
                               ((tblPersonal.Teilnahmen*100)/(tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - 
                                tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO))           
FROM dbo.tblPersonal WHERE tblPersonal.aktiv=1 and 
                        tblPersonal.MaID=@MaID)
```

**But this one would work:**

```
SELECT @NoShowRate=
      (SELECT ((tblPersonal.Teilnahmen*100)/(tblPersonal.Anmeldungen -
           tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO))      
FROM dbo.tblPersonal WHERE tblPersonal.aktiv=1 and tblPersonal.MaID=@MaID)
```

Please help in defining a scalar-function (?) with a case select.
Michael

```
 MaID AnmeldungenXX AnmeldungenNO Teilnahmen Reliability
    1   0   0   23  NULL
    2   1   0   1   NULL
    3   2   1   2   NULL
    4   0   0   0   NULL
    5   0   0   0   NULL
    6   0   0   1   NULL
    7   0   0   0   NULL
    8   1   0   35  NULL
    9   0   0   0   NULL
    10  0   0   0   NULL
    11  1   0   25  NULL
    12  2   4   17  NULL
    13  0   0   0   NULL
    14  0   0   0   NULL
```

Comment: You appear to be missing an `end` to your `case` expression. Without having your table (simplified), some (sample) data and knowing what your expected results *are*, I'm not sure I can help further at this time.

Comment: Yes, some data makes it more clear:  

tblPersonal, and the function should calculate the Reliability per MaID

1 0 0 23 NULL
2 1 0 1 NULL
3 2 1 2 NULL
4 0 0 0 NULL
5 0 0 0 NULL
6 0 0 1 NULL
7 0 0 0 NULL
8 1 0 35 NULL
9 0 0 0 NULL
10 0 0 0 NULL
11 1 0 25 NULL
12 2 4 17 NULL
13 0 0 0 NULL
14 0 0 0 NULL

Comment: If you want to show is the data, please *edit* your question (link at bottom left). You can't do much formatting in comments and that makes sample data really difficult to read.

Comment: Damien, I am very sorry, I do NOT understand this ... formating issue, I fight with this for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first select statement is missing end and it should be like the following one

```
SELECT @NoShowRate=(Select case when tblPersonal.AnmeldungenXX = 0 and tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO = 0 then 0 
                             when tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO > 0 and tblPersonal.Teilnahmen=0 then 0
                             when tblPersonal.Teilnahmen > tblPersonal.Anmeldungen then 100
                        else ((tblPersonal.Teilnahmen*100)/(tblPersonal.Anmeldungen - tblPersonal.AnmeldungenNO))    end         

                 FROM dbo.tblPersonal WHERE tblPersonal.aktiv=1 and tblPersonal.MaID=@MaID)
```

Comment: Thanks Hossam, it worked.
Each case has to end with 'end', which I overread all the time.

Comment: That's great to know so please mark it as answer since it is worked with you :) or your still need support ?

Comment: Sorry Hossam, I can't find out HOW to mark it as answered!!  
A very useful, very informative site, but very strange to handle..!